# APP in AWS ECS Fargate Can't Connect to Remote Database in Liquid Web

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nestjs, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have deployed a Nest.js application on AWS ECS Fargate, and am using a Network Load Balancer with two associated Elastic IPs, one for each subnet. Now, I am attempting to connect to our remote database on Liquid Web. I have already added both IPs to the WHM firewall whitelist settings, and have also added them to the Control Panel under Remote MySQL Hosts. I have checked the security group outbound rules and the network ACLs outbound rules, and everything seems to be in order. Could you please advise on what else I need to check?

Additionally, I have attempted to connect to this remote database via localhost using the same database URL string. After allowing my local public IP in the firewall and Remote MySQL Host, I was able to connect to the database.

Also, I can connect to my app using the elastic IP address associated with the network load balancer after deployment.

I hope you can help me. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When a server on AWS like an EC2 server or ECS server makes a new outgoing connection to something on the Internet, that connection does not go through the load balancer or make use of the load balancer in any way. Load balancers are proxies for incoming requests only.

In order to give your ECS services a static public IP address, you have to have at least one NAT gateway in a public subnet of your VPC, and deploy your ECS services to private subnets (subnets with a route to the NAT Gateway) in the VPC. Outbound requests will then be proxied through the NAT Gateway, and you will be able to whitelist the NAT Gateway's Elastic IP address on your external service.